# Pattern string formatting

Tags: coffeescript

It is possible to format string like this:

```
text = 'text'
formatted = "Text: #{text}"
```

What about the following?

```
pattern = "Text: #{text}"
text = 'text'
formatted = ???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pattern formatting in coffeescript is a part of coffeescript->javascript compiler.

So,

```
pattern = "Text: #{text}"
```

instantly compiles into

```
pattern = "Text: " + text;
```

It's why

```
pattern = "Text: #{text}"
text = 'text'
```

will throw an error "text is not defined".

But you can wrap it in a function like this:

```
pattern = (text) -> "Text: #{text}"
text = 'text'
formatted = pattern text
```

or like this:

```
pattern = ({text1, text2, text3}) -> "Text: #{text1}, #{text2} and #{text3}"
text1 = 'text'
text2 = 'awesome text'
text3 = 'another text'
formatted = pattern {text1, text2, text3}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, the string interpolation syntax doesn't work like that.
This is possibly a better way to achieve the exact same thing though:

```
pattern = 'Text: #{text}'
text = 'text'
formatted = pattern.replace /#{text}/, text
```

Comment: While this would work, I think it is bad advice to introduce a regex to solve this problem